# pthread runs multiple times

Tags: c, pthreads

I want my each of my threads call multiple functions. How can I achieve that? Right now I have code for threads calling just one function:

```
pthread_attr_init(&attributes);
if((tid1 = pthread_create(&thread[0],&attributes,produce,NULL)))
{
    printf("\nError in the producer thread\n");
    printf("\n");
}

if((tid2 = pthread_create(&thread[1],&attributes,consume,NULL)))
{
    printf("\nERror in the consumer thread\n");
}

pthread_join(thread[0],NULL);
pthread_join(thread[1],NULL);
```

Would calling pthread_create spawn two new threads?

Comment: The function you pass to `pthread_create` is like `main` to your program: its starting point. You can then put what ever you want as code inside this function... What is your problem?

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is how I can put multiple functions in pthread_create.

Comment: @ballballbobo Can you put a function inside another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "pass" multiple functions to `pthread_create()`. There's simply no provision for that. However, you can call whatever functions you want in the thread function, just like any other function call.

```
void *produce(void *arg)
{
   func1();
   func2();
   ...
}

void *consume(void *arg)
{
   funcx();
   funcy();
   ...
}

int main(void) 
{
...

if((tid1 = pthread_create(&thread[0],&attributes,produce,NULL)))
{
    printf("\nError in the producer thread\n");
    printf("\n");
}

if((tid2 = pthread_create(&thread[1],&attributes,consume,NULL)))
{
    printf("\nERror in the consumer thread\n");
}
...
}
```

Or if what you wanted was separate threads for each of those (e.g. `func1` and `func2` in the sample) functions to be separate threads, then you just need to call `pthread_create()` as many times with each of these functions as an argument (i.e. thread function).